# Can't get slash to appear correctly

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, but I'm trying to make the slash only appear on the first drop down level of a menu. I'm doing this in php.

Here is my code

```
function appendMainNav($subid){

    global $_PAGES_TABLE, $_HTTP_ADDRESS;
    $subWrapper='';
    $subClass='';
    $mainClass='mega-nav-wrapper overlay-bg';
    if($this->hasParentMenu($subid) > 0){
        $subWrapper = 'sub-nav-main-wrapper'; 
        $subClass='sub-nav-wrapper';
        $mainClass='';
    }
    $p=1;
    $str = "";
    $str.= '<div class="'.$subWrapper.'">';
    $str.=' <ul class="'.$mainClass.''.$subClass.'">';
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM $_PAGES_TABLE P WHERE P.parent='".$subid."' AND P.show='1' AND P.active='1' ORDER BY num");
    while( $result = mysql_fetch_object($query) ){
        $page = new Page($result->id);
        $page->setFromDatabase();
        $lastClass='';

        if(($page->linkto != '0' && $page->linkto != 0 && $page->linkto != '') || $page->linkto == '#'){
            $linkto = $page->linkto;    
        }else{
            $linkto = $page->id;
        }

        $appendArrow='';
        $arrowSelect = "";
        $slash ='       ';

        if($this->hasChildrenMenu($page->id) > 0){

            $slash = '      /';
        }

        $str .='<li class="subnav_item'.$lastClass.'"><a class="'.$appendArrow.'" href="'.getSEOLink($linkto).'">'.$page->{'title'.$langVar}.''.$slash.'</a>';
        //$str.='<li><span>/</span></li>';

        if($this->hasChildrenMenu($page->id) > 0){

            $str.=  $this->appendMainNav($page->id);
        }

        $str.='</li>';
        $p++;

    }

    $str.='     </ul>';
    $str.='</div>';
    return $str;
```

At the moment it only appears on the sub menu item that has a drop drop down as well. The second drop down mustn't have anything.

My menu looks like this

```
menu 1   menu 2 / menu 3

     submenu 1 
     submenu 2 
     submenu 3
```

and this is how I want it to look

```
menu 1 /  menu 2 / menu 3 /

     submenu 1 
     submenu 2 
     submenu 3
```

Comment: looking at the code you will have the slash on every result that has a children menu, is this the expected behaviour?
So if you have a three level menu it will show One / Two / Three, you want it to be One / Two Three ?

Comment: yep the way I want it is One/Two Three

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution would be to add a flag to the function and change the conditional:

```
function appendMainNav($subid, $noSlash = false){

    ...

        if(!$noSlash){

            $slash = '      /';
        }
        ...

        if($this->hasChildrenMenu($page->id) > 0){

            $str.=  $this->appendMainNav($page->id, true);
        }
     ...
```

Comment: I have tried what you suggested it's not 100%. I have updated my question to show what my menu looks like

Comment: You can update also with how you want it to look! To know what you do want.

Comment: I've updated the question with how I would like the menu to look

Comment: So then you don't have to check if there are children to add the  slash, but just check the $noSlash variable, updated my code.